# Oracle changes password

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle11g

From time to time, Oracle is changing the password for my account. My project has one database pooling for each 60 seconds and another for each 600 seconds.
I don't believe this is the cause, but it abruptlies changes the password causing my code to try to login with wrong username or password that leads to an account lock.

The password is always the same and there's no way the program is trying to connect with a different username/password than the valid ones.

Comment: Passwords are checked case-sensitively in oracle11g, however they were case-insensitive in oracle10g or earlier versions. Check your password's case.

Comment: The case is right. Consider the following scenario: I start the server, it works. I make some corrections, restart the server, it doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting?  ORA-01017?

Comment: Do you have a profile set up that limits the number of concurrent connections?

Comment: @cagcowboy according to our DBA, there's nothing like that

Comment: how do u know your app is the only one (trying to) connect to db using that username?

Comment: @tbone I don't, but I'm the only one allocated to this project, so no other developer should be accessing this account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that it was a configuration in the company lib that I was not aware of... sorry for all the mess....

Answer (score 4):

ORA-28000 is not a password change, it is an account lock either by the DBA or because the wrong password has been entered more than  FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS times.

I have to wonder if there isn't one chunck of code somewhere that has a hardcoded, incorrect password that is being run. That or you just get too many people mis-typeing a password in a given time span.

If you want to track failed logins to try and identify what is causing this, check this link: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tracking_counting_failed_logon_signon_attempts.htm

Note that, from ORacle 10.2 on, the default for FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS in profiles is 10, not the unlimited that it used to be. for the default profile, check it with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_PROFILES
WHERE  profile = 'DEFAULT' AND resource_name = 'FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS';
```

Bet you get 10 back, and that this is the issue. You can update to a higher value, or backl to unlimited e.g.

```
ALTER PROFILE default  LIMIT failed_login_attempts UNLIMITED;
```

(I think that is the right syntax - I'm away from my DB at the moment)

Comment: Good catch. I'm pretty sure Oracle does **not** change the password by itself.

Comment: Before the account lock error I get several login failed. My DB connection is a singleton that is retrieved always from the same place  ...

Comment: Note that from ORacle 10.2 on, the default for failed login attempts is 10. Prior to that it was unlimited. I will update the answer with more details in a sec....

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Yes, I confirmed with the DBA that the limit by default is 10. But what we want is to understand why is this happening..

Comment: Well, I can't possibly tell you why you are having failed logins. I would suggest, however, looking at that link and setting up login failure auditing to try and see of you can figure it out. IT could be a connection pooling issue if you are running more concurrent clients than the pool will allow, or for some other reason. I couldn't begin to guess the cause, but can only give the tools for you and your DBA to figure it out.

Comment: Two things you might consider while figuring it out: 1) check the SESSIONS_PER_USER setting on the profile to see if that is causing the login failure, and 2) assuming that this is a DEV box, ask the DBA to set the PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME on the profile to a short value so that you notice the error, but that you regain access quickly and without constantly needing DBA intervention while you get this sorted out.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton The PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME is in days right? Should this value be integer? I mean, what if I want to set it for one minute? Can I use 0.00069 ?

Comment: Yes, fractional values are permitted so for n minutes use n/1440 to set the value.